# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars Python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to get an 11 digit number from the user and make a 3x3 array with the first 9 numbers. I also want to create new arrays with the sum of every column and row.

But I get an error and I could not understand the error message. It's the title of question.

Can anyone explain to me why I get that error and how to fix it?

```
import numpy as np
id = (input('enter your 11 digit id number : '))
dizi = []
for i in range(0, 9):
dizi.append(id[i])
dizi = np.reshape(dizi, [3, 3])
print(dizi)
toplam = int(id[-1]) + int(id[-2])
rowToplam = [sum(int(dizi[i]))for i in range (4)]
print(rowToplam)
columnToplam = [sum(int(dizi[:,i]))for i in range (4)]
print(columnToplam)
```

Comment: You need to fix your indenting.  The code, as of now formatted will not work.

Comment: i must be blind. :) thanks for suggestion. it works now.

Answer (score 0):

What the error says is that the function expects a single value but you pass an array instead (in your case `int()`).
Indeed, if you consider your code:

```
rowToplam = [sum(int(dizi[i]))for i in range (4)]

dizi = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
#    [[1 2 3]
#     [4 5 6]
#     [7 8 9]]

print(dizi[0]) # [1 2 3] <-- it's not a single value
```

To achieve your task you may simply use the `sum()` method specifying the axis. See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html).

```
dizi = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3) 

rowToplam = dizi.sum(axis=1) # [ 6 15 24]
columnToplam = dizi.sum(axis=0) # [12 15 18]
```

or change your code to:

```
n_rows, n_cols = dizi.shape
rowToplam = [sum(map(int,dizi[i])) for i in range(n_rows)]   # [6, 15, 24]
columnToplam = [sum(map(int,dizi[:,i])) for i in range(n_cols)] # [12 15 18]
```

where you use `map()` in order to apply the `int()` function to all the elements in case they are not.